# Script to replace string in files with parent folder name

Tags: windows, batch, find-and-replace

I have a series of folders which each contain an `index.html` file. Within these files is a `div` tag with an ID of `S030_010`.

What I'd like to try and do is replace this string with the parent folder name. I'm not even sure if this is possible and no idea where to start. These files are all on my local Windows 10 machine.  I have in the region of 150 folders/files to process and may have to do this again in the near future

I'm not sure what to even search to get started on this and wondered if anyone is able to provide some guidance on this?

Example of Folder structure:

```
S010_010
- index.html
S020_010
- index.html
S020_020
- index.html
```

Comment: comment to me after adding the following to your question: What version windows? 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: what text editor are you using?

Comment: google search: notepad++ regex replace html

Comment: google search: powershell edit html